# React formatting issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

I have the following (which I did not write):

```
   render: function () {
        if(this.state.loading){
            return <div><span><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...</span></div>
        }else if(typeof this.state.listing.id == 'undefined' || !this.state.component){
            return false;
        }
        return (
            React.createElement(eval(this.state.component), {
                listing: this.state.listing,
                onClose: this.handleClose,
                options: this.state.options
            })
        );
    }
```

This is inside of a React.creatClass.  I am foreign to react but simply need a wrapper div around this part:

```
                React.createElement(eval(this.state.component), {
                    listing: this.state.listing,
                    onClose: this.handleClose,
                    options: this.state.options
                })
```

How can I add a simple div around that piece so I can properly style this component?

Comment: `eval(this.state.component)` oh wow, this looks like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it in another JSX tag. It'd be best if you can get rid of that stray `React.createElement` call and only use JSX.

```
render: function () {
  if(this.state.loading){
    return (
      <div>
        <span>
          <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
          Loading...
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  } else if(typeof this.state.listing.id == 'undefined' || !this.state.component) {
    return false;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {React.createElement(eval(this.state.component), {
        listing: this.state.listing,
        onClose: this.handleClose,
        options: this.state.options})
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The real question here, is what on earth is that `eval` doing there?